# ios-sim command to start iPhone 6 or iPad 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova, ios-simulator

I am not able to start an iPhone 6 with ios-sim utility from GitHub. I have Xcode 6 GM. The ios-sim utility is the latest one which supports iOS 8 devices.

If I use the ios-sim with the retina and tall option it starts iPad retina or iPhone 5. I am not sure what would be the command line to start iPhone 6.

I downloaded the utility from: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim.

There is an option for Xcode 6+ (i.e `devicetypeid`. Is this what I can use? How do I find the `devicetypeid`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

get a list of potential devices like this:

```
$ ios-sim showdevicetypes
```

use them like this:

```
$ ios-sim start --devicetypeid com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6
```